# How do you build older gcc versions? Errors about crti.o not being found

Tags: 11.10, gcc

How can I build an older gcc (specifically, 4.5.2) on Ubuntu 11.10 and avoid errors about "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory"?

I've done a bit of digging and found several similar items, but none that actually resolve my issue:

- I've verified all my packages (libc6-dev and the like) are re-installed per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69119/linking-problems-after-updating-to-11-10)
- I've verified crti.o exists in /usr/lib32 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, and that my ld.so.conf is configured to look in those directories
- I've verified that prepending my make invocation with LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu works, but would like to avoid this (it becomes a diverging point in makefiles)
- I've tried various things with --with-build-sysroot, but with no success (read: maybe I just don't know the right flag to set)
- When running with strace (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91576/crti-o-file-missing/91595#91595)), I can see the bare reference to crti.o:

  13240 open("crti.o", O_RDONLY)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. Making symbolic links from `/usr/libs/crt?.o`  to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt?.o` solved the problem for me.

Comment: This does work, yes. I was hoping for a solution that was more along the lines of tweaking the gcc installation rather than mucking with underlying file structures, though...

Comment: I wanted to add that in my case, I recompiled glibc and GCC, but I forgot to get rid of an older slackware-gcc variant that was at /usr/bin/. When I removed the latter, I could compile certain things again (such as gcc again).

Answer (score 10):

Even very new versions of GCC fail with that message. It's because the new Debian/Ubuntu releases (will) support multiarch (i.e. installing binaries for multiple machines in one file-system), so the libraries have been moved away from the standard places.

There are GCC patches to fix it [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2011-08/msg01649.html) (not yet approved final versions, but correct for Ubuntu), and they probably apply to older GCC without much effort, maybe. I think you need to configure GCC with *--enable-multiarch*, or something.

In the meantime, creating soft links is a good fixup:

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu/crt*.o .
```

(the folder name will be different on 32-bit installations).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the point about it being multiarch. I was hoping for resolution on "why" it stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with a couple of workarounds that might be useful for you.

First, build GCC with `LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, so that the build bootstrap process knows where to find the `crt?.o` start files.

Then, instead of making `crt?.o` symlinks in `/usr/lib` where they affect your whole system, you can symlink those three files into the `${prefix}/lib/gcc/...` directory corresponding to the `${prefix}/bin` directory that the `gcc` executable is installed in.  That's actually almost at the top of its search path for the start files, so it will find them -- but they don't affect anything else.

In my case, the specific directory to put them in was `lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.3.2/`; you can find the right one because it already has other files like `crtbegin.o` in it.

Answer (score 1):

I built GCC 4.1.2 on Ubuntu precise x86_64. As you did, I took a look at the strace of last command "xgcc" looking for 32bit c runtime, grep-ped /32/ as follows.
C runtime in mine is in /usr/lib32 which is provided by libc6-dev-i386 package.

```
fgrep /32/ strace-output.txt | grep /usr/lib | head -1
access("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.1.2/32/crti.o", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So, I created the crt?.o symlinks in the directory xgcc looked for.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.1.2/32
cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.1.2/32
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/crt1.o 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/crtn.o 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/crti.o
```

I successfully built GCC 4.1.2 with it.