# apt-get gcc 4.7 multilib

Tags: 12.04, gcc

I followed the instructions from @jokerdino [here in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113291/how-do-i-install-gcc-4-7)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7
```

But to get a successful compilation I've had to:

1. export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
2. sudo  ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o   /usr/lib64/crti.o
3. sudo  ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o   /usr/lib64/crtn.o

Which I understand effectively breaks the Ubuntu multilib model.
So how do I compile the correct way and remove the links?
Because now I'd like to cross-compile for 32 bits.
(Using Precise)

Comment: @jokerdino *ping*

Answer (score 2):

I removed the symbolic links posted in my question.

Then with @shuttle87's suggestion in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69119/linking-problems-after-updating-to-11-10)
I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils  
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential  
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev  
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.7-multilib   
sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++-4.7-multilib
```

Then this worked:  *gcc -m32 foo.c*
to compile for 80386.

But to compile for x86-64 *gcc foo.c* did NOT work.

So I tried:

```
 gcc foo.c -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

But that didn't work either. Finally had to:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Before *gcc foo.c* would work.

I used "readelf -h" to verify that the executables
were 80386 and X86-64.

Don't understand why the 'L' flag didn't work...

But at least I got those symbolic links removed and can cross-compile easily enough using the "export".

Comment: Note: when using CMake I didn't have to worry about exporting /usr/lib/x86_64. All I had to do was supply the "m=-m32" option when needed.